# I want to filter the data for column Species for Species name “versicolor” and I also want to select only ‘sepel_length’ and Sepel _width’ columns

Tags: r

I have written this code in R Studio:

```
select(filter(iris,Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length,Species=="versicolor"))
```

but it's throwing an error

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.

i Input `..1` is `Sepal.Width`.

x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a double

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    select(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length,Species) %>% 
    filter(Species=="versicolor")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(iris,  Species == 'versicolor', select = c(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, Species))
```